# QtCreator - no rule to make target when building windeployqt

Tags: qt, build

I have installed `C:\Qt\5.6\` on Windows 10. I have started QtCreator from there, and opened `C:\Qt\5.6\Src\qttools\qttools.pro` in it. I expanded the node, and right-clicked on `designer` and did `Build "designer"`, it built fine (using mingw)

Now, I try to do the same for `windeployqt`, but it fails with:

```
:-1: error: No rule to make target 'C:/Qt/5.6/mingw49_32/lib/libQt5Bootstrapd.a', needed by '..\..\bin\windeployqt.exe'.  Stop.
```

[image: qttools]

What am I missing, and how can I get `windeployqt` to compile?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think I got it. First, I tried looking for `*bootstrap*` named files in C:\Qt, and it turns out, this file exists:

```
C:\Qt\5.6\mingw49_32\lib\libQt5Bootstrap.a
```

So, the only difference from the filename in the error message, `libQt5Bootstrapd.a`, is that there isn't a `d` at the end of the filename (without the extension) - and then I remembered, that `d` probably represents a Debug version of the .a library.

As you can see on the screenshot, there is a button down left in the Qt Creator GUI, where it says "qttools ... (monitor icon) ... Debug". This is "Deploy Configuration" - I clicked there, and set the Deploy Configuration to "Release" - and then tried building `windeployqt` again - and this time, it worked without an error message.